# ActiveMQ command line equivalent to tibrvlisten

Tags: activemq-classic, tibco-rv

I was wondering if the community here knew of a way to listen to topics on an ActiveMQ broker via the command line similar to TibcoRV's 'tibrvlisten'

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there are some [command line tools](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-command-line-tools-reference.html), but they don't offer send/listen support...

your best bet is to use one of the following to create messages, listeners and browse message data

- JMX - http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
- web console - http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html
- JMeter - http://jmeter.apache.org/